# google sheet latest data fetch

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-sheets-api

I need to automate an OTP capture for my selenium-python automation scripts, Now the otp is getting updated in the google sheet and I am fetching the same using google API using the following code. Now My script runs every hour, so in that case, I will have new OTP which is getting updated every hour. How to get the latest updated data from google sheet using python?

"otp" is my sheet name. and I am using the `"range="otp!a1"` for getting the value of first row and first column. So during the second run it should be `"range="otp!a2"`for getting the value of second row and first column and so on...

Now my goal is to capture the latest value during each execution.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1YYfxsX2FsdXLXqRwx0WTTlD7ru56m1D'
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,range="otp!a1").execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
print(values)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the values of the last row, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,range="otp!a1").execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

#### To:

```
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="otp").execute()
values = result.get('values', []).pop() # or values = result.get('values', [])[-1]
```

- In this case, `range` is the sheet name.
- If you want to retrieve the value of column "A", you can also modify as follows.

  ```
    values = result.get('values', []).pop()[0]
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: excellent bro...it helped a lot